# Encountering ErrorIntenarlServerError when creating an event using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I Was able to create an event on a not delegated calendar but failed on the delegated calendar when using this endpoint:

> [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calendarId}/events](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/%7BcalendarId%7D/events)

I also tried to put a wrong access token and calendarId on the request just to make sure if I can encounter the same error message but It didn't trigger the issue.

This is the object we're passing.

**CalendarRequest**

```
{
    start = new MicrosoftDateTimeZoneRequest() {
        dateTime = dateTimeOffset.ToString(dateTimeFormat),
        timeZone = "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    end = new MicrosoftDateTimeZoneRequest() { 
        dateTime = dateTimeOffsetEnd.ToString(dateTimeFormat),
        timeZone = "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    subject = $"{activity.CustomerName} {activity.ActivityName} {activity.ActivityType}".Trim(),
    body = new MicrosoftItemBodyRequest() { content = activity.Details + (activity.CustomerId > 0 ? ("|" + clientURL) : ""), contentType = "HTML" },
    location = new MicrosoftLocationRequest() { 
        displayName = "Home"
    },
    attendees = new List<MicrosofAttendeeRequest>() {
        new MicrosofAttendeeRequest() {
            emailAddress = new MicrosoftEmailAddressRequest(){address =  "karlo@tapnztest.onmicrosoft.com", name = "X TAP" },
            type = "resource"
        }
    },
    allowNewTimeProposals = false,
    isOrganizer = true
}
```

And this is how I call the endpoint

```
var calendarResponse = GetCalendarEvent(accessToken);
var calendarID = calendarResponse.value.Where(a => a.owner.address == "test@tapteam.co.nz").FirstOrDefault()?.id;
var addCalendarEventRequest = new RestClient($"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calendarID}/events");
var request = new RestRequest();
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
request.AddJsonBody(calendarRequest);
var response = addCalendarEventRequest.ExecuteAsync(request, Method.POST);
```

Payload

```
{
  "subject": "CC - 1st Meeting Confirmed CC - 1st Meeting Confirmed",
  "body": {
    "content": "test",
    "contentType": "HTML"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2021-02-25T15:30:00.000+13:00",
    "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2021-02-25T16:00:00.000+13:00",
    "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "location": {
    "address": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "displayName": "Home",
    "locationEmailAddress": null,
    "locationUri": null,
    "locationType": null
  },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address": "karlo@tapnztest.onmicrosoft.com",
        "name": "Karlo TAP"
      },
      "proposedNewTime": null,
      "status": null,
      "type": "resource"
    }
  ],
  "allowNewTimeProposals": false,
  "transactionId": null,
  "isOrganizer": true
}
```

Comment: The issue could be with the payload as well, could you please sahre the payload that you are using.

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma done updating the question thank you

Comment: Use the fiddler and see how is the payload being sent. It should be something like this `{
  "subject": "Let's go for lunch",
  "body": {
    "contentType": "HTML",
    "content": "Does mid month work for you?"
  },
  "start": {
      "dateTime": "2019-03-15T12:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "end": {
      "dateTime": "2019-03-15T14:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address":"AB@domain.com",
        "name": "Adele Vance"
      },
      "type": "required"
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma  added the payload

Comment: May be [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#accessing-a-shared-calendar) could be the reason.

Comment: Hhmm but I was able to access the calendar using GET "/me/calendars/{id}/events"

Comment: This is fixed, the issue is that `transactionId` property should not be null